# Custom content translation links

Tags: 7, navigation, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual Drupal site in english & french. At the bottom of every page is the content translation link, however I want to place this in a custom location on page.tpl.php.
So if I hide the content translation links in the configuration, how do I call it via a function on the page template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Incase there was no translation node, I send the user to the homepage.

```
$tpath = translation_path_get_translations($_GET['q']);
if ($language->language == 'en') {
    if (array_key_exists('fr', $tpath)) {
        $tlink = "<a href='/fr/" . drupal_lookup_path('alias', $tpath['fr'], 'fr') . "'>Français</a>";
    } else {
        $tlink = "<a href='/fr/'>Français</a>";
    }
} else {
    if (array_key_exists('en', $tpath)) {
        $tlink = "<a href='/" . drupal_lookup_path('alias', $tpath['en'], 'en') . "'>English</a>";
    } else {
        $tlink = "<a href='/'>English</a>";
    }
}

print $tlink;
```